# Pass integer from jQuery to PHP Session array

Tags: php, jquery, session

I am trying to pass an integer from jQuery to a Session array in PHP.
I have a button with an id, this id should be added to the session array.

I started the session with:

```
// ADD SESSION START TO HEADER
function hook_session() {
if(session_id() == ''){
     session_start(); 

     $parts=array();

     $_SESSION['parts']=$parts;
}    
}
add_action('wp_head', 'hook_session');
```

My jQuery:

```
$('.product-button').click(function(){
    $id = $(this).val();
    $id = parseInt($id);
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: $id,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (result) {
            console.log('Yay it worked');
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log('Something went wrong');
        }
    });
});
```

my PHP:

```
<?php
array_push($_SESSION['parts'],$_POST[$id]);
print_r($_SESSION['parts']);?>
```

Where am i going wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: I think you should edit your post to provide a little more information - like: What are the results of this code? Do you see your "Yay it worked" message in the console or "Something went wrong"? Is the array populated or no? Also, what is `ajaxurl`, presumably you're sure you're posting back to the PHP page?

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave When I run the function I get "Something went wrong". ajaxurl is a jquery var which contains the url to the php file which contains the php in my original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't give a name to the `POST` parameter.

```
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl,
    type: 'POST',
    data: { id: $id },
    success: function (result) {
        console.log('Yay it worked');
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log('Something went wrong');
    }
});
```

Then in the PHP, use `$_POST['id']` to access the parameter.

```
<?php
session_start();
array_push($_SESSION['parts'],$_POST['id']);
print_r($_SESSION['parts']);
?>
```

Also, `print_r()` doesn't produce `JSONP` format output, so don't use `dataType: 'jsonp'`